# OpenSSL, OCSP & IPv6

Tags: openssl

For the majority of OpenSSL commands, it is possible to force the use of IPv6.

E.g.:

```
openssl s_client -6
```

I did not find any similar option for `ocsp`.

Did I miss something, is it just not implemented?

Comment: It appears you did miss nothing, I cannot find anything useful for IPv6 in combination with `oscp`.

Comment: In what context might you need this?  Could you not manually resolve the DNS using `ping6` and then simply use `openssl s_client [address]`

Comment: @PhilipCouling I do not really need it, from time to time I test using IPv6 only. As many OpenSSL tools have the option (e.g., ```s_client```), I was wandering why the exception.